# On debugging: Cannot copy file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

Every launch of my Windows 10 UWP aplication in debug mode after the first one fails with the following message

```
Error : DEP0500 : The folder "C:path\projectname\bin\x86\Debug\AppX" could not be deleted. 
Access to the path 'thestory.exe' is denied.    thestory
```

The only fix I have found so far is to restart VS (Community Edition 2015) after every single debugging session. Which is extremely annoying. It seems like the debugging process is not being cleaned up correctly.

Any ideas / suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean it occurs for a simple blank project or only for a specific project? Have you updated to VS 2015 update 1? https://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2015-update1-vs

Comment: Do you have any unterminated threads or any references which are being held open? Do you make use of 'using' blocks on all disposable objects? This looks like you have a thread holding the program open. We need more information to be able to help further.

Comment: You could try adding an event handler for Closing, check if there is a debugger attached, and if so, call `Application.Current.Exit();`. This will kill off the application if you're using an attached debugger. UWP documentation states not to use this in production applications, so check if there is a debugger attached before calling it with `if (Debugger.IsAttached)`

Comment: Just add a comment here. It happens a few times when I tried to run my UWP tests, which is technically UWP app hosting all the tests. So I believe this is not fixed. And even after I restarted VS again and again, it doesn't help.  I am using VS2015 + Update 2.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and tried every solution on the net I could find.

The problem only starts after I publish an app for the first time. 
The fix is unchecking the "Enable ClickOnce security settings" which is in the application properties Security Tab.

Answer (score 0):

VS will sometimes fail to terminate MSBuild32 after running in debug mode, but as your message states 'Access to the path 'thestory.exe' is denied.', it suggests you have a reference being held open.

Do you use static initialisers in your code? I have encountered this problem before trying to use singletons in C# using a java style implementation. 
The static reference to self was holding the class open, and as I never explicitly nulled the reference, the program failed to exit.

If you need to ensure that the application will close in VS, you can add an event handler to the closing event, and implement the following:

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached) {
    Application.Current.Exit();

    // If Application.Exit fails, try...

    // CoreApplication.Exit();
}
```

It's worth noting that if you application won't exit cleanly, you almost certainly have a reference being held open in your code.

It was asked in the comments if this happens when you create a new blank UWP application, run it, then try to exit.

I recommend you test this as a matter of urgency - if this application has been problematic for some time yet blank UWP applications work fine, it points to a problem in the code.

Forcing the application to exit will terminate any .NET classes, but if you call anything outside of the managed runtime, it will remain resident after the runtime is terminated

Comment: It DOES occur every debugging session as it wrote in the question, so it is really much more than a minor irritation to me right now. It also looks like the issue has been occuring for more than a year now (see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/41f06523-5b36-4b22-86b3-32a4b366e732/visual-studio-error-on-deploy-dep0500?forum=toolsforwinapps), so waiting for a fix is not an option.

Comment: You could try downgrading to VS 2013, as it is much less of an issue in that version. Also, I did see that you wrote that it occurs in every debugging session, and I realise this is not a minor irritation (I've been putting up with this for 2 years up to now). Do you have any unterminated threads or any references which are being held open?